# Create a zero vector of size n in Python

Tags: python, arrays, vector, zero

I would like to create a function of n. I would like the function to return a zero column vector of size n.

To clarify if I choose n=3, in return I get:

```
np.array[[0], [0], [0]]
```

Comment: `np.zeros((n, 1))`?

Comment: Thanks. That helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
def colvector(n):
    return np.zeros((n,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(n):
    return np.array(n*[[0]])
```

is that the function that you need?

Comment: Please explain 'why' this may be the answer.